# How do I include directive inside directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

nested directive is not working because it execute as a plain html..

```
//nested directive
directive("uploadinput", function(){
   .... 
})

//directive:
directive("mydirective", function(){
  return {
     restrict: "E",
     templateUrl: "partials/mydirective.html",
     scope: {data: "="}
});
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-repeat='i in data.model'>
    <uploadinput  ng-model='i.model'></uploadinput> <!--nested directive is not working-->
</div>
```

Comment: How is the `uploadinput ` directive implemented. Are there any errors in the console.

Comment: Please provide proper details. What does *"execute as a plain html"* mean? Why is `ng-model` used on an element that isn't a form control? WHere is the code for the directive? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `ng-model` on non-form elements is perfectly reasonable, I do it all the time for custom inputs.  More details on the question would indeed be helpful, though.